"PHP Session Data Not Being Retrieved on Server"
while i am targeting /api/signup/sendotp end point then session id i am getting while debugging that session data set or not ex-message
:
"OTP sent successfully"
session_otp
:
630124
session_otp_timestamp
:
1712249609
success
:
true
but once i am targetting again to server /api/signup/register then my session is empty  ex-Session startedCookies: Array ( [PHPSESSID] => s12ldv18upc71fjtv6k7rbcdfj )
Session: Array ( )
Warning: Undefined array key "otp" in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\signupRoutes.php on line 98
session otp:
{"success":false,"message":"OTP not set in session"}
my code file
<?php
// Allow cross-origin requests
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://localhost:80");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");


require 'server.php';
require 'mailSender.php';
require 'cors.php';
cors();


$conn = establishDatabaseConnection();


if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    echo "Session started";    // for  debugging
}

// Function to sanitize user input
function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

// Function to generate OTP
function generateOTP($length = 6) {
    return rand(pow(10, $length-1), pow(10, $length)-1);
}

// Function to check and expire session OTP if older than 10 minutes
function expireSessionOTP() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['otp']) && isset($_SESSION['otp_timestamp'])) {
       
        $current_time = time();
        $otp_timestamp = $_SESSION['otp_timestamp'];
        if (($current_time - $otp_timestamp) > (10 * 60)) {
         
            unset($_SESSION['otp']);
            unset($_SESSION['otp_timestamp']);
            unset($_SESSION['email']); 
            echo "Session OTP expired!";
        }
    }
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/api/signup/sendotp') {
    
    $email = isset($_POST['userEmail']) ? test_input($_POST['userEmail']) : '';

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid email address'));
        exit;
    }

    // Generate OTP
    $otp = generateOTP();

    // Store OTP and timestamp in session
    $_SESSION['otp'] = $otp;
    $_SESSION['otp_timestamp'] = time();
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email; 

    // Send OTP to user email
    $mailBody = "
    <p>Dear valued user,</p>
    <p>Welcome to RishikeshCityGuide! We are delighted to have you as a part of our community.</p>
    <p>As part of our security process, please use the following one-time password (OTP) to verify your account:</p>
    <h1 style='font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #ff0000;'>$otp</h1>
    <p>Please enter this 6-digit OTP to complete the verification process. If you did not request this OTP, please ignore this email.</p>
    <p>Thank you for choosing RishikeshCityGuide!</p>
    <p>Best regards,<br>RishikeshCityGuide Team</p>
    ";

    if (sendEmail($email, 'Verification Code', $mailBody)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'OTP sent successfully', 'session_otp' => $_SESSION['otp'], 'session_otp_timestamp' => $_SESSION['otp_timestamp']));
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'OTP sending failed'));
    }
}

// Route for user registration
elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/api/signup/register') {

    //  Debugging
    echo "Cookies: " . print_r($_COOKIE, true) . "<br>";
    echo "Session: " . print_r($_SESSION, true) . "<br>";
    echo 'session otp: ' . print_r($_SESSION['otp'], true) . "<br>";
    // Validate OTP
    if (!isset($_SESSION['otp'])) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'OTP not set in session'));
        exit;
    }

    $otp = isset($_POST['otp']) ? (int) test_input($_POST['otp']) : '';
    expireSessionOTP();

    if (empty($otp)) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'OTP is required and cannot be empty'));
        exit;
    }

    // Check OTP
    if ($_SESSION['otp'] !== $otp) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid OTP'));
        exit;
    }

    // Extract other user data
    $email = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? test_input($_SESSION['email']) : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? test_input($_POST['password']) : '';
    $confirmPassword = isset($_POST['confirmPassword']) ? test_input($_POST['confirmPassword']) : '';
    $mobileNumber = isset($_POST['mobileNumber']) ? test_input($_POST['mobileNumber']) : '';
    $plan = isset($_POST['plan']) ? test_input($_POST['plan']) : '';
    $status = isset($_POST['Status']) ? test_input($_POST['Status']) : '';
    $role = isset($_POST['Role']) ? test_input($_POST['Role']) : '';
    $category = isset($_POST['category']) ? test_input($_POST['category']) : '';

    
    if (empty($password) || empty($confirmPassword)) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Password fields are missing'));
        exit;
    }

   
    if ($password !== $confirmPassword) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Passwords do not match'));
        exit;
    }

   
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // Insert user data in database
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (EmailId, Password, MobileNumber, Plan, Status, Role, Category) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    if ($statement) {
        $statement->bind_param("sssssss", $email, $hashed_password, $mobileNumber, $plan, $status, $role, $category);
        if ($statement->execute()) {
            // Registration successful, clear session data
            unset($_SESSION['otp']);
            unset($_SESSION['otp_timestamp']);
            unset($_SESSION['email']);

            echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'User registered successfully'));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error registering user'));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error in preparing statement'));
    }
}
?>

my cors file code
<?php
function cors() {
    
    
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
        // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:80");
        // header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');   
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization');
    }
    
 
   // Allow specific headers
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
    
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}, Authorization");
    else
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *, Authorization"); 

    // Allow credentials
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

    exit(0);
}
}

?>

please help me in this that why i am not getting session data
i tried  to add header and in  frontend i add withCredentials: true  const response = await axios.post(RegisterRouter, params, { withCredentials: true });

As to your first code block posted, you can only specific the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header once: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMultipleAllowOriginNotAllowed

I didn't read how you were using the function test_input, but I can pretty much guarantee it shouldn't be used. The function's comment is Function to sanitize user input and the body includes calls to stripslashes and htmlspecialchars, and this is almost certainly a destructive thing that will eventually cause you a headache, and might even be doing it right now. Use prepared statements to safely put data in SQL, and escape user-supplied content when rendering.

Unrelated to your problem, but in modern PHP $category = isset($_POST['category']) ? test_input($_POST['category']) : ''; can be replaced with just $category = $_POST['category'] ?? ''; which I personally think is much easier to read. Just noting my opinion since I'm trying to read through this.

Looks like line 98 is echo 'session otp: ' . print_r($_SESSION['otp'], true) . "<br>";, and that's where that key doesn't exist. So your debug code is tripping the warning that the next line is checking for

if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {     session_start();     echo "Session started";    // for  debugging } is unecessarily bloated. Just session_start(); is fine. PHP will take care of the rest itself, without you needing to write any code to manage it. (i.e. if there's already a session it'll just make it available to the script when you run session_start(), it won't create a new one. This is already covered in the documentation).
